# Print return value after program execution

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am wondering how to set option to auto print return value after every program execution in terminal without typing `echo $?`.

Is it something that can be setup? Codeblocks has that feature.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there are two ways. One is to set `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `.bashrc`, the other - to set command substitution in `PS1` for the `echo $?` command.

**Method 1:**

From the bash manual page:

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> ```
>       If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each
>       primary prompt.
> ```

Whatever you set this variable to, will be run before drawing the prompt each time. Demo:

```
$> PROMPT_COMMAND=" echo 'Last command exited with'  \$? 'code'  "
Last command exited with 0 code
$> ls /etc/passwd > /dev/null
Last command exited with 0 code
$> ls /etc/asdf > /dev/null
ls: cannot access /etc/asdf: No such file or directory
Last command exited with 2 code
$>
```

Note the use of `\$?` . For permanent change, save it in `.bashrc`

**Method 2**

Suppose my `PS1` prompt is set like this:

```
PS1='
user@ubuntu:$> '
```

If I want to run some program each time this prompt is redrawn on the screen (which is after each preceding command runs), I would need to use `command substitution $(. . .)`  and set it in the prompt like so:

```
PS1=' [ $? ] 
user@ubuntu: $> '
```

Demo:

```
$> PS1=' [ $? ]
> $>_ '
 [ 0 ]
$>_ ls /etc/passwd > /dev/null
 [ 0 ]
$>_ ls /etc/asdf > /dev/null                                                                                                      
ls: cannot access /etc/asdf: No such file or directory
 [ 2 ]
$>_
```

Notice that I split my PS1 into two lines, top will have `[ exitcode ]` and bottom  `$> <blank space>'` . That is why there is `>` before `$> '` on the second line (The leading `>` is `PS2` prompt for multiline commands ) .  Alternatively, you could do something like this ( notice the `$'...'` structure):

```
  $> PS1=$'[ $? ] \n$> '                                                                                                  
[ 0 ] 
$>
```

Comment: +1 That actually works. I'm not doubting anybody with a 27k reputation, but apparently the prompt isn't a "command", so using $? in it doesn't get $? reset to zero like I thought it might be - even using the first method which executes echo with no errors.

Comment: `PS1` is just text that is being printed before getting user input - nothing more than that. It's not immune to parameter expansion and command substitutions, so you could put anything into `$(...)`, for example `$( pwd  )` and it would show there. I've used that with a custom script to show laptop battery power, for example

Comment: @mchid  what do you mean ?

Comment: @mchid "Prior to issuing each primary prompt", hence after the last command has finished executing.

Comment: @mchid it's run before the prompt is printed - so before you get to type the next command.

Comment: @mchid that command runs before writing the PS1 on the terminal screen. So for example ls exits , then runs this promt command, then ps1 shows up. In your case, how were you setting up the beep ?

Comment: I got it, I don't know how I set it last time but it works correctly now.

Answer (score 4):

A method which I picked from [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Functions#Display_error_codes) is to `trap` `ERR`. `trap` is used in Bash to run commands when a signal is received, or for certain other events. An `ERR` trap is ran whenever the current command line terminates with an error - the return value is not 0. (If it did terminate normally, the return value would obviously be 0.)

So, for example:

```
trap 'printf "\ncode %d\n\n" $?' ERR
```

Then:

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ false

code 1

$
```

(Note: no message after the `echo` command which ran successfully - [What does it mean when I type a command and the terminal does nothing?](https://askubuntu.com/q/492507/158442))

The Arch Wiki tip went ahead and colorized the message, so that you get a noticeable yellow message:

```
EC() { echo -e '\e[1;33m'code $?'\e[m\n'; }
trap EC ERR
```

Effect:

[image]

In effect, all I need to do is keep an eye out for a yellow `code` in the output to know a command failed.