# What are the implications of using PROMPT_COMMAND like this?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, 23.10

I would like to insert the return code of the last command in reverse red color and inside brackets (`[]`) plus a colon (`:`) just before the bash (`PS1`) prompt. But, only if the return code is non-zero, i.e., the last command returns an error (generally speaking).

I am investigating the use of the special `PROMPT_COMMAND` *bash* environment variable like this (by putting it in my `.bash_aliases` file):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='( x=$? ; [[ "$x" == "0" ]] || echo -e -n "\e[7;31m[$x]\e[0m:" )'
```

In this code, I need to test whether the return code is non-zero and run the `echo` command accordingly. So, I need to first store it in an environment variable. In order not to overwrite an environment variable with the same name (`x`), I run the whole code in a sub-shell.

Is there any more efficient or recommended method for this which is also simple?

Comment: Also you can misuse [an `ERR` trap instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/743298/158442): `trap 'printf "\e[7;31m[%s]\e[0m:" $?' ERR`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `PROMPT_COMMAND` for that, you can use just `PS1`:

```
PS1='$(e=$?; if ((e)) ; then echo "\[\e[7;31m\][$e]\[\e[0m\]:" ; fi)\A \u@\h \w\$ '
```

The `$(...)` command substitution runs in a subshell, so there's no variable accessible from outside.

The extra `\[` and `\]` are needed to tell bash what parts of the prompt have zero length.

I use more sophisticated logic which needs `PROMPT_COMMAND`, but I just set

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_command $?'
```

and define a function `prompt_command` in my `.bashrc` which uses `local` variables.

Comment: I ended up using something like this: `PS1='$( x=$? ; [[ "$x" == "0" ]] || printf "\[\e[7;31m\][$x]\[\e[0m\]:" )'"$PS1"`. Thanks for the "zero length" tip also!